# Android Phone connected as ttyUSB device

Tags: usb

I need to connect my Android phone or tablet to my Ubuntu 16.04 and use smstools or minicom for reciving/sending sms for further data processing. In all tutorials about minicon or smstools they discribe connected Android device as ttyUSB*, whereas in my case every time I connect my Samsung S6 (stock Android 6.0.1) or Samsung Tab S2 device (stock Android 6.0.1) it shows up in dev directory as libmtp-1-2. not as tty device.

When I point in minicon to /dev/libmtp nothing is happening.

Are my devices incompatible to run such software or do I need to root my devices to deal with stock system limitations?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Because Android doesn't talk on USB that way anymore... Not for many years, your tutorials are out-dated.